# How to plot array on to map with lat and long?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 360-by-180 array and what to plot on to geobasemap.

The 360-by-180 array is basically earth and the cells are the property at that given lat-long.
When I first plot it using contour(X) the axes are from 0-360 and 0-180.
Then I used

R = georasterref('RasterSize', [180 360], ...
'RasterInterpretation', 'cells', 'ColumnsStartFrom', 'south','RowsStartFrom', 'west', ...
'LatitudeLimits', [-89.5 89.5], 'LongitudeLimits', [-179.5 179.5]);
contourm(x,R)

created the plot with axes from -90 ~ +90 and -180 ~ +180

Then when I try to plot on a geobasemap, it overlays with the map that I called out because the maps are on degree coordinates like -90degree ~ +90degree and -180degree ~ +180degree.
It seems like MATLAB doesn't let these number coordinate and degree coordinate systems plot onto each other.

Is there any way to plot the 360*180 array onto a map with -90degree ~ +90degree and -180degree ~ +180degree coordinates?

```
0.03    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.03
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NaN NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0
0.01    0.05    0.05    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   0   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN 0.02    0   0   NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0   0   0
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.01
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0   0   0
NaN NaN NaN 0.04    0   0   NaN NaN
NaN NaN 0.03    0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   0.02    0.03    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0.01    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The above is the small section of my array, because putting the full 180-by-360 array is too long and impossible so this section is all I can put.
But the full 180-by-360 array is just much more section of this example.

Comment: Have you considered just remapping the coordinates?

Comment: Can your clarified what do you mean by remapping the coordinates?

Comment: 359->-1, 358->-2, etc. Use something like fftshift to fix the data

Comment: I don't think that we can change the column and row into negative, the array is 360-by-180 so the first cell is X(1,1); I was wondering if there's anything that can make the first cell as X(90,-180) that's why i used the georasterref  to center the lat,long at (0,0) at the center of the map (which in the initial array will be at X(180,90))

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Randomly generated data is OK

Comment: I had edit the section of array, but i cant put full 180-by-360 array onto it. But the full 180-by-360 array is basically many this kind of sections combined together. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have able to plot a 360-by-180 satellite track onto a map.

```
R = georasterref('RasterSize', [180 360], ...
'RasterInterpretation', 'cells', 'ColumnsStartFrom', 'south','RowsStartFrom', 'west', ...
'LatitudeLimits', [-89.5 89.5], 'LongitudeLimits', [-179.5 179.5]);

axesm('miller');
% geoshow('landareas.shp')
load coastlines
plot(coastlon,coastlat) % load coastlines

contourm(X,R,'LineWidth',3)
```

As for X is the 360-by-180 array/matrix